# UITableView tapping index doesnt scroll to section

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I have a tableView where I have implemented section headers and I have the section titles appearing along the right hand side. However, when I tap the index it doesn't scroll to that section even though I can see in my logs that it is returning the correct section.

Here is my method for tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitles:atIndex

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {

NSLog(@"Title: %@", title);
NSLog(@"index: %d", index);

return [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex:index];
}
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: You didn't provide enough info here... What code are you using to scroll to the section after its been tapped? (It won't just scroll automatically.)

Comment: It should, according to many online tutorials. It did for me, at least. Now it stopped working and I'm stuck with the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create alphabets scroll. This will helps.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

 //section index in tableview
    alphabetsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"#",@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H",@"I",@"J",@"K",@"L",@"M",@"N",@"O",@"P",@"Q",@"R",@"S",@"T",@"U",@"V",@"W",@"X",@"Y",@"Z", nil];

}

-(NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

 return alphabetsArray;

}
```